# What is the correct escaping or quoting of whitespace in a classpath (!path) element in FitNesse?

Tags: java, escaping, classpath, whitespace, fitnesse

Let's say I have the following classpath definition in a FitNesse suite:

```
!*> '''Classpath'''
!path /home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/test-classes
!path /home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes
!path /home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/fitnesse/fitnesse/20121220/fitnesse-20121220.jar
*!
```

I have tried the following forms of quoting or escaping:

- Vanilla whitespace: `!path /home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes`
- Backslash: `!path /home/stewart/white\ space\ test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes`
- Double backslash: `!path /home/stewart/white\\ space\\ test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes`
- Double quotes: !path `"/home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes"`
- Single quotes: !path `'/home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes'`
- % encoding: `!path /home/stewart/white%20space%20test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes`
- Using +'s: `!path /home/stewart/white+space+test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes`
- Unicode sequence: `!path /home/stewart/white\u0020space\u0020test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes`
- Unicode sequence with extra backslash: `!path /home/stewart/white\\u0020space\\u0020test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes`
- Wildcards: `!path /home/stewart/white*space*test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes`
- FitNesse wiki escaping: `!path !-/home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes-!`

With vanilla whitespace and some of the quoted whitespaces, the tests don't run at all and I get the error:

```
Could not find or load main class space
```

According to the error logs, FitNesse is attempting to escape the whitespace with quotes. It's invoking the `FitServer` with this command:

```
java -cp fitnesse.jar:"/home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/test-classes":"/home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes":/home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/fitnesse/fitnesse/20121220/fitnesse-20121220.jar fit.FitServer linux-desktop 9123 10
```

With some of the escaping the tests do run, but they fail because FitNesse cannot find the fixtures on the classpath, which I believe means that the substitute for the whitespace (+, %20, \u0020, etc) is not getting resolved as whitespace, but as a path literal.

I'm beginning to think that it's not possible to do this in FitNesse ...

---

Update: I also tried experimenting with the `COMMAND_PATTERN` and `CLASSPATH_PROPERTY` FitNesse variables, as detailed in the documentation about [customizing test execution](http://fitnesse.org/FitNesse.UserGuide.CustomizingTestExecution)

---

FitNesse version is 20121220.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the first thing to note is that this phenomena **does not happen** on Windows. FitNesse automatically encloses classpath elements contained whitespace with double-quotes, as already noted in the question. The command which FitNesse generates is:

```
java -cp fitnesse.jar:"/home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/test-classes":"/home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes":/home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/fitnesse/fitnesse/20121220/fitnesse-20121220.jar fit.FitServer linux-desktop 9123 10
```

On Windows, this would be:

```
java -cp fitnesse.jar:"C:\white space test\example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\target\test-classes":"C:\white space test\example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT\target\classes":C:\.m2\repository\org\fitnesse\fitnesse\20121220\fitnesse-20121220.jar fit.FitServer windows-desktop 9123 10
```

And it just works!

Given that Windows is the operating system where it's common to have whitespace in directory (folder) names, I could have stopped there; but I wanted to dig deeper, as you can occasionally get whitespace in directory names on Unix-like systems (MacOS springs to mind.)

Digging into FitNesse source code, the class we are interested in is `fitnesse.testsystems.CommandRunner`. In the method `asynchronousStart()` it uses Java's `Runtime.exec()` method.

`Runtime.exec()` has overloaded methods. In some, the command is a `String` which gets parsed with a `java.util.StringTokenizer`. In others, the command is already a `String[]` and does not get further parsed.

In other words, this fails:

```
String cmd = "java -cp fitnesse.jar:\"/home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/test-classes\":\"/home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes\":/home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/fitnesse/fitnesse/20121220/fitnesse-20121220.jar fit.FitServer linux-desktop 9123 10";
String[] env = new String[]{};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env);
```

Whilst this works:

```
String[] cmd = new String[] {
    "java",
    "-cp",
    "fitnesse.jar:\"/home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/test-classes\":\"/home/stewart/white space test/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/target/classes\":/home/stewart/.m2/repository/org/fitnesse/fitnesse/20121220/fitnesse-20121220.jar",
    "fit.FitServer",
    "linux-desktop",
    "9123",
    "10";
};
String[] env = new String[]{};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, env);
```

Conclusion: it's a bug in FitNesse.

---

Update: this is fixed FitNesse versions 20140623 onwards.

Comment: I also found this was useful reading regarding commandline classpaths containing whitespace on unix: http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t130004-java-command-containing-classpath-in-quotes-on-unix.html